# Consuming WCF Restful Service hosted by IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, rest, post, .net-4.0

I have successfully deployed my WCF restful web service to IIS 7.  I have verified that my service is working when I call it from a browser in IE via a something like "https://myserver/mservice.svc/postuser/JohnSmith" .  The method is a POST and I have verified that my IIS configuration allows for POSTS.

My issue is as follows.  We are using a 3rd party Software as a Service application that allows for external web service calls.  It allows you to configure the URL "https://myserver/mservice.svc/postuser/" and then you can choose a parameter.  When I call the web service from the external application, a 404 error is registered in IIS.

I think there must be some difference between the way I call my webservice "https://myserver/mservice.svc/postuser/JohnSmith" and the way the SAAS application is calling my external web service.  The web service is attempting to pass the username, but I cannot detect how it is constructing this.

Do I need to write a web enabled front end for my web service that is hosted in IIS that can handle XML?  I'm assuming this is how the SAAS application is trying to pass the username onto my web service.

Thank you all in advance for your ideas and help.

Comment: Sounds like the third party program is appending metacrap. Can you use fiddler or something to see what URL it's constructed?

Comment: Try using Fiddler to intercept the raw request message and inspect on what is causing the issue. Also try enabling Tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service